# Am I allowed to do this as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, asymptotics, approximation

I have these two functions over real $x>0$ (with $a,b$ finite real constants)
$$ g(x,a)=\frac a x \cos x+x-15\sin x \qquad (1) $$
$$ g(x,b)=\frac b x \cos x+x-15\sin x \qquad (2)$$

I want to evaluate these functions as $x\to\infty\;$; am I correct that in this limit, the functions $(1)$ and $(2)$ behave in a similar way (independent of $a$ and $b$) as follows?
$$ g(x,a)\approx g(x,b)\approx g(x)\approx x-15\sin x+\mathcal{O}(\frac 1x)  $$

Comment: You can also neglect  $15 \sin x$ too.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to evaluate these functions as $x\to \infty$?  Do you mean that you want to evaluate the limit?  or that you are looking at asymptotics?  If the former, the limits are both infinite.  If the latter, both are $x + \mathcal{O}(1)$ (as $\left|\frac{-15\sin(x)}{1}\right| \le 15$ as $x \to \infty$ (or, really, for all $x$)).

Comment: @XanderHenderson The second, I am looking for their asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @XanderHenderson May I ask you to kindly check my previous question as well? it is related to this concept of asymptotics.

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically, if you have a sum of bounded and unbounded monotonic terms,  you can ignore all the bounded terms.  You have $|15 \sin x|\leq 15$,  so adding or subtracting a number in this range is going to have less and less an impact on something that is growing to infinity, with the impact in ratio terms going to 0.